# Ms Sql repetitive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

http://postimage.org/delete/pwnan1ud4/

there are repetitive rows **(column Name : aracId)** in the picture as linked above. How can i modify query for the unique row.

Comment: pls attach your image to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is not viewable, try adding `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` clause. Example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
With Cte as 
(
Select row_number() over (partition by arac.aracID order by arac.aracID ) as row
-- other columns
left join ...
Where .... and 
tip.tipadi in ('Kamyon','Kamyonet','Tir')
)
Select cte.aracID, cte.Model, ..........
from cte where cte.row=1
```